# separately created JWT not getting authorized in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, jwt

I have a scenario where i have to create JWT in javascript app manually so i used the code here

https://codepen.io/jpetitcolas/pen/zxGxKN

and in my asp.net core i have a simple values controller with a function decorated with Authorize

```
[Authorize]
    [Route("GetValues")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> GetValues()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
```

and in my startup.cs i have

```
       public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(x =>
            {
                x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                x.SaveToken = false;
                x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("My very confidential secret!!!")),
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = false, //set this to true when a reasonable lifetime has been determined based on jwt generation
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false
                };
            });
        services.AddControllers();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseAuthentication();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
```

as you can see i am using the same secret in token and trying to validate in asp.net core but when i use post man to call https://localhost:44364/GetValues with Authorization key set to "Bearer " i get 
401-UnAuthorized. Am i missing something ?

any idea what i might be doing wrong here.

**UPDATE**

```
 public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {            
        // services.AddAuthorization();
        services.AddControllers();

        // var hmac = new HMACSHA256(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("My very confidential secret!!!"));
        // var symKey = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SymmetricSecurityKey(hmac.Key);

        var secretKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("My very confidential secret!!!"));
                var signinCredentials = new SigningCredentials(secretKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature);

        services.AddAuthentication(opt =>
        {
            opt.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            opt.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            options.SaveToken = true;
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false,
                ValidateLifetime = false,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                ClockSkew = System.TimeSpan.Zero,
                IssuerSigningKey = signinCredentials.Key
            };
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        // app.UseMiddleware<AuthenticationMiddleware>();
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            // ...
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthentication(); // this one first
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

**Update 2**

even if i set ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false means i dont even want to validate the key even then i get 401 Unauthorized .
**to recreate** we can just create a blank .net core api project with sample values controller and copy paste my Startup.cs and then the bearer token from https://codepen.io/jpetitcolas/pen/zxGxKN which is 
*eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6MTMzNywidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJqb2huLmRvZSJ9.EvTdOJS-fbffGHLyND3BMDwWE22zUBOCRspPZEHlNEw*

and lasty just use postman like this

[image]

Comment: The firstly thing is to put `app.UseAuthentication();` between `app.UseRouting();` and `app.UseAuthorization();` , then use fiddler to trace the request to check whether any error exists in `WWW-Authenticate` header .

Comment: now i am using them in this sequence 
app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication(); // this one first
            app.UseAuthorization(); and i will check fiddler just now.

Comment: header seems to be ok i am sending 

Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6MTMzNywidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJqb2huLmRvZSJ9.DgYz3ZaZiKThbpHj2Bg44cdGqdPm3QwrJZpVBhmy5dE     as my token

Comment: What i said is response header(WWW-Authenticate) when 401 code return .

Comment: www-authenticate →Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature is invalid"

Comment: i Added entire Startup.cs as well, in the update section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using the same signing key, in your js fiddle, you have a String as key and in your validation you are expecting symmetric key.

In js you have below line, where secret is your signing key:

signature = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(signature, secret);

Using secret as the signing key should resolve the issue.

Comment: i used         IssuerSigningKey = HMACSHA256(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(mySecret)); in my startup.cs code but the problem is that "IssuerSigningKey" requires the type of "SecurityKey". 
i ideas ?

Comment: i generated the HMACSHA256 like this 
  var hmac = new HMACSHA256(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("MySecret"));
            var symKey = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SymmetricSecurityKey(hmac.Key);
and passed it in "IssuerSigningKey". didnt worked

Comment: On your signincredentials can you try to use SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature ?

Comment: i changed it but still getting 401 unauthorized
"Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature is invalid""

Comment: Okay I ll try it out on my local when I get home.

Comment: Now i think your answer is correct just verifying if i use “MySecret” in both JS code  and dot net code its not working and when i am using “My very confidential secret !!!” As my key it works. Wierd

Comment: i used a string "Yeh To Ho Ga Bus" with 4 spaces in it it works . dont know if this is something we have to do when writing secret keys

Comment: found my answer here as well.
https://auth0.com/blog/brute-forcing-hs256-is-possible-the-importance-of-using-strong-keys-to-sign-jwts/

Comment: Oh god, you found it, I got confused with the variable name in js. But makes sense now. I updated my answer and the reason it doesn’t work with some strings is because there are requirements for it to of certain bytes depending on what library you are using to Hmac it.

Comment: Agreed yes that was also the problem . Thabkyou so much